# USGS Multiple Dates listed and I want to know what they mean

Tags: qgis, time, date, topography, usgs

I want to take a look at a piece of land over time and evaluate the change in topography over time. I am using USGS to download some data and I realized they give you a list of dates that correspond with a DEM download. Does anyone know what these dates mean and which one I would rely on as the date that the image was taken?
[image]

Comment: Images aren't taken in 1x1 degree chunks, which is why the metadata specifies a 63-year duration.  That same metadata asserts it couldn't have been more recent than 2015.